# count substring occurrence in every combination

Tags: java, regex

I have a string `phahahahoto` and I need to find how many times the String `haha` appear in the above string. If you look closely it appears 2 times.
My code is below and I get the output 1 instead of 2.

Code is written in java.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("haha");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("phahahahoto");
int count = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
    count++;
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Probably you should use `find(int offset)` method with `lastMatchStart + 1` in the loop condition. (`int lastMatchStart = -1` for initialization.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the **count** in one line like this also:

```
int count = "phahahahoto".split("(?=haha)").length - 1;
//=> 2
```

Answer (score 4):

Use lookaheads in-order to do overlapping matches. If you clearly noticed that the string `haha` was overlapped. If you pass `haha` as regex, it won't do an overlapping match, since the pattern `haha` matches the first `haha` substring which leaves you only the last `ha` part. Lookarounds won't consume any single character. So it would be able to match only the boundaries.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?=haha)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("phahahahoto");
int count = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
     count++;
}
System.out.println(count);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lU4oT6/1)

Here it matches the boundary which exists before each `haha` . See the above demo link.